# How to restore variables in Tensorflow r1.0

Tags: tensorflow, restore

After upgrading Tensorflow to r1.0, the restore command does not seem to work.
For example, can anyone tell me what is wrong with the following?

```
def foo():
    v1 = tf.Variable(1., name="v1")
    v2 = tf.Variable(2., name="v2")
    v3 = v1 + v2

    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

        saver.save(sess, "temp")

        # do something

        saver.restore(sess, "temp")
```

From the last line, I got an error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for temp
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save/Const_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]
```

Tensorflow documentation still holds the explanation of old versions for this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TensorFlow 1.0 has a bug where it doesn't recognize `tf.Saver.restore()` filenames that contain only a filename (and no path component). This will be fixed in the next version, but for now you should be able to use the following workaround to add a path component:

```
saver.restore(sess, "./temp")
```